# Adding constraint with CASE WHEN THEN

Tags: sql, constraints, case

I am a beginner in the SQL field, currently working on a project of my own.
I am trying to add a constraint on a column to help me display different values for different (2) cases.
My columns are, as it follows:

```
DATA    DATE    
NR_SLIDE    NUMBER  
TOTAL   NUMBER  
NR_ZILE NUMBER  
ID_C    NUMBER  
ID_F    NUMBER  
COST_SLIDE  NUMBER
```

Basically I need to display total with two options: 
1. when nr_slide>10 I need to make a discount of 5
2. when nr_slide<=10, no discount.

My code attempt (last one) looks like this:

```
ALTER Table Factura f
add CONSTRAINT ck_total CHECK (
    CASE 
        WHEN nr_slide>10  
            THEN total=(nr_slide*cost_slide*nr_zile-5) 

            ELSE total=(nr_slide*cost_slide*nr_zile) 

    END = nr_slide);
```

I am getting the message:

> ORA-01735: invalid ALTER TABLE option

Could you help me fix this issue? Might there be something I have not defined previously?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think you want:

```
ALTER Table Factura f 
    ADD CONSTRAINT ck_total
        CHECK ( (nr_slide > 10 AND nr_slide = nr_slidecost_slidenr_zile - 5) OR
                (nr_slide <= 10 AND nr_slide = nr_slide* cost_slide * nr_zile)
              );
```

You may need to take `NULL` values into account as well.